# My Index is created and shows up in Kibana, but why is it missing from the Kibana map?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, geojson

I have a GeoJSON file that contains the boundaries of 3 US States, I was able to successfully load this into ElasticSearch using Python, and when I go to Kibana, I see my created index.  Issue is I do not see it on the Kibana map, what am I missing?

Here is a sample of the geojson.

```
{
"type" : "FeatureCollection",
"name" : "Outline_date",
"features" : [
    {
        "type" : "Feature",
        "geometry" : {
            "type" : "Polygon",
            "coordinates" : [
                [
                    [ -77.9741261597, 35.2186618283 ],
                    [ -78.3147315937, 35.7579537654 ],
                    [ -79.2513965371, 35.6444186208 ],
                    [ -78.541801883, 34.7645212497 ],
                    [ -77.9741261597, 35.2186618283 ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "properties" : {
            "timestamp" : "20190909071754.9718596",
            "Name" : "North Carolina",
            "abbrev" : "NC"
        }
    },
    {
        "type" : "Feature",
        "geometry" : {
            "type" : "Polygon",
            "coordinates" : [
                [
                    [ -79.4784668264, 37.1771430737 ],
                    [ -79.4784668264, 36.8649214259 ],
                    [ -78.541801883, 36.8649214259 ],
                    [ -78.541801883, 37.1771430737 ],
                    [ -79.4784668264, 37.1771430737 ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "properties" : {
            "timestamp" : "20190909071755.0440474",
            "Name" : "Virginia",
            "abbrev" : "VA"
        }
    },
    {
        "type" : "Feature",
        "geometry" : {
            "type" : "Polygon",
            "coordinates" : [
                [
                    [ -81.2098777824, 34.5942185327 ],
                    [ -81.718192491, 34.6305267262 ],
                    [ -81.7465762772, 34.2331537199 ],
                    [ -81.2382615686, 34.1968455264 ],
                    [ -81.2098777824, 34.5942185327 ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "properties" : {
            "timestamp" : "20190909071755.0442809",
            "Name" : "South Carolina",
            "abbrev" : "SC"
        }
    }
]
}
```

[Snapshot of Kibana With Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wzha.png)

Comment: What does your index mapping look like?  Kibana does not support nested fields in visualizations to my knowledge, and judging by what you have now, it appears the coordinates are nested a few levels deep.

Comment: The mapping is nested also, what will a non-nested version look like?